# rails couldnt find profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I'm currently getting this error. **Couldn't find Profile without an ID**. I am trying to create a profile form that can be edited and updated once a user has signed up. Ive setup a **has_one** association of **users** to **profiles**.  Heres my controller for profile.

**Note** - Using devise

**routes.rb**

```
 resource :profile , :only => [ :edit, :update]
```

**profile_controller.rb**

```
 class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
     def edit
         @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
     end

     def update
         @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
         @profile.update(params[:profile].permit(:example,:example))
     end
 end
```

**user.rb model** - create profile when new user signs-up

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  after_create :create_profile
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

private
  def create_profile
   self.profile = Profile.create
 end
end
```

**Heres the form -  edit.html.erb**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3">
           <%= render 'layouts/sidenav' %>
       </div>

 <%= form_for :profile, method: :patch do |f| %>
   <div>
      <%= f.label :example %>
      <%= f.text_field :example %>
   </div>

   <div>
       <%= f.label :example %>
       <%= f.text_field :example%>
   </div>

   <div>
       <%= f.submit %>
   </div

   <% end %> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What controller is throwing the error, edit or update?

Comment: profile controller **edit action**

Comment: Are you redirecting to the profile edit action after creating a user?  Because I'm not sure your after_create callback would actually assign the profile's user_id

Comment: I think your on to something because when I delete a user their profile still exist with the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form_for is using a symbol for profile rather than the instance variable...

You need:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  # etc
<% end %>
```

Also, you shouldn't need the 'patch' method in there as Rails knows what to do with an ActiveRecord instance in a `form_for`.

**Edit:**

If you're trying to use a path with doesn't include the profile id to edit you'll have to do something like so in your edit action (assuming you have `current_user` to refer to the user who is logged in):

```
def edit
  @profile = current_user.profile
end
```

When you use the `params[:id]` to find the profile, Rails is looking for an id in the url params (which you don't have).

Likewise in your `update` action you'll need to find the profile based on the user.

```
def update
  @profile = current_user.profile
  # etc
end
```

Comment: Still throwing the same error. **Couldn't find Profile without an ID**

Comment: What's the path you're on? Something like `profiles\1\edit`?  Is the error when you load the page or submit the form?

Comment: cool I seem to now get missing template view. But I simply just did a redirect to the same page :/

Comment: Is that after you submit the form?  You need to redirect from your update action.

Answer (score 0):

`Couldn't find Profile without an ID` would be a typical exception when

```
 Profile.find(params[:id])
```

is passed a null value.  So it seems params[:id] is not being set.